# issue on forge with hasFile conditional

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I can't for the life of me figure this. I have a `form` submitting files just fine on `local` but when pushed to production on `forge`, the `hasFile` conditional isn't `triggering` when I upload an attachment:

```
if ($request->hasFile('screenshot')) {
  ...
}
```

There are no errors in the `log`, not sure how this could affect it but the functionality broke after I had support raise my `client_max_body_size` in `nginx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue had to do with a corrupted php.ini on the digital ocean server. Since the file was being refused, hasFile was not being triggered.